# What do I need to increase the storage in my HP Proliant DL380 Gen9 server?

Tags: hard-drive, sas, upgrade

Some background: The server has 3... sections on the front. Left, middle and right. I know that all 3 sections can be filled with disks if needed, however the server we got came with the right hand section full of disks, the middle section just has a blanking plate and the left section has an optical drive.

If I want to use the middle section for storage what do I need to do? Behind the blanking plate there is no chassis to put the disks in, there is no room to plug it in in the smart array card, I can't even see anywhere to plug them in to the server?

The current disks are:
2 x 146GB SAS 15K (RAID 1) (O/S)
6 x 900GB SAS 10K (RAID 5) (4.5TB)

I realise I'd have to destroy the raid and rebuild it with all the new disks but that's fine. Having more storage is more important.

[image: Here's a pic of the front of the server so you can see what I mean]

The other option of course is just to replace the current disks with higher capacity ones but I don't like the idea or wasting the current disks. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely need 1 x HPE P/N: 768857-B21 but you don't mention which disk controller you have - if it's the internal B140i then that only supports 10 disks so you'd need to move up to a Pxxx series of controller - if you have a Pxxx series controller then please let us know so we can advise on any cables you may need. Oh and try to get off RAID5 please, we hate it and it can be very dangerous for your data, essentially it's been dead for many years now - try to use R1/10 or R6/60.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I knew I'd left something out. The Smart array is a P440ar Controller. I'm happy to move from RAID5, that's just how it was originally setup.

Comment: The P440ar supports 200 drives so that side of it is fine but can you see if your current 8 x SFF backplane has two cable connections to that P440ar or just one? If just one then you just need the part I listed above - if it's using both connectors on the P440ar then you will need to switch to something like a P842 so you have enough ports - I don't have a DL380 Gen9 with the P440ar in our lab to check sorry.

Comment: That's ok, you've been a great help, I'll look into it and see what I find before I come back to you. Thanks!